# Find names of persons who own at least one house in each city in Canada using tuple relational calculus

Tags: relational-calculus

I am working on the following exercise:

> Using tuple relational calculus, find names of persons who own at least one house in each city in Canada.

The relevant relation schemas are:

- `City (city-name, country-name, area, population)`
- `House (hno,#rooms, stno, owner-name)`
- `Street (stno, city-name, length)`

<sup>**Note**: Bolded are keys.</sup>

This is what I came up with:

```
{ h.owner-name | House(h) and forAll c (City(c) and c.name="Canada") -> 
(Exists s(Street(s) and s.city-name = c.name) and Exists x(House(x) and x.stno = s.stno and x.owner-name = h.owner-name) ) }
```

How I read this aloud:

- "For all *Canadian* cities, there exists a street with a HOUSE *x* that has the same owner as the HOUSE *h*."

Is this correct? I've peen pulling my hair out trying to understand tuple relational calculus.